# Brother MFC-7860DW and scan through network

Tags: scanner, brother, simplescan

We have about 15 PCs in office with Ubuntu 14.04/15.10/16.04 and 2 Brother MFC-7860DWR that connect to LAN(Ethernet). I downloaded and installed drivers from Brother's support site(i used manual on that site). I have no problem with printing and almost with scanning. :)

For scan i used this manual on all PCs:

1. After install drivers:

   ```
   brsaneconfig4 -a name=(name my device) model=(model name) ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
   ```
2. And then checked(all was fine):

   ```
   brsaneconfig4 -q | grep (name of my device)
   ```

On 12 PCs - all works fine, but on 3 PCs i have one interesting problem. Printing works fine, network scanners added, and i see them in terminal:

```
Devices on network
  0 Buh                 "DW7860-2"          I:192.168.88.202
  1 Dev                 "DW7860-2"          I:192.168.88.203
```

But when i launch simple scan and start Scan - it hangs. And in Document -> Preferences -> Scan Source  i don't see any scaners, if i click to Scan Source and try to choose one - Simlpe Scan hung. 
And this problem only on 3 PCs. I know for sure, two of them are Ubuntu 14.04, but last one i can't remember, maybe 14.04 too.
I reinstalled drivers - it didn't help :(

Comment: If you are using ufw or another firewall, are the appropriate ports open? Quick test - disable ufw and retry.

Comment: ufw status inactive